# DLL hell with Unity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, unity-container

I'm having big problems with implementing Unity DI in my project. This has been asked about here before but i need your help anyway.

The error I get is

```
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
```

Then the No Symbols Loaded tab in VS

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.pdb not loaded
Version 4.00.1.0 
Original location C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\25e027a5\1b5eb1ca\assembly\dl3\36014eea\59864550_5097d101\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dl
```

From the other questions here i learned to run the *FUSLOGVW*. There I saw nothing about Unity. The only thing there that might be related to Unity is Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriceLibrary.Logging?

Then there's the GAC. Where can i find it and what can i do there to check if anything is wrong there?

Also, there is nothing about Unity in my web.config. Should there be?

Any other tips to solve my problem please?

Answer (score 3):

Your error: `StackOverflowException` tells that you have circular dependency: (A->B->C->A) between your classes and `Unity` can not resolve it. `Unity` goes by this chain over and over and save to stack addresses of calling functions and soon stack capacity is not enough and happens `StackOverflowException`. Check very carefully all dependencies that are resolved by means of `Unity` taking into account `Unity`'s resolving rules that you set and perform separation of classes to subclasses in accordance with single responsibility principle (**S**OLID). Also if your IDE supports UML diagrams you can create them to represent dependencies between classes in grafic form it may help you very well.